# QA app for small team

Tags: quality-center, web-application

What is the best app for writing QA tests in a small team ? ( 5 peoples ?)

Actually, we use emails.

Comment: [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/ondemand/signup/?product=jira-software.ondemand) is only 10$ a month for up to 10 users, and you don't need to host it yourself. You can log bugs, create test suites and test cases, as well as feature requests, and export reports

Comment: I love the spirit of the question, but I think we need more details. What is your current workflow? "Emails" is quite broad. Could you elaborate on your process?

Comment: @costrom Is that a comment? Or an answer? Looks like an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wiki is excellent and flexible replacement for archived emails. But it is not a valid replacement for communication about the process, and following the rules the team agreed on.

Jira is good for tracking bugs and efforts. For documenting the process, not so much. Wiki allows you to create custom "encyclopedia" of test-related knowledge, steps to follow, procedures, rules etc. Accessible from a browser with just few mouseclicks.

Jira forces all info into single mental mode (bug).  In wiki, pages can be accessed and linked different ways, according to mental model which is best for different audiences/approaches/problems.

Of course, such flexibility comes with price. You need to be disciplined to use wiki right.

We use Bugzilla for structured part of our process, and wiki for the flexible unstructured part (documenting subsystems). Because often the documentation should change when fielding other bugs later, but it is a lot of work, so just linking bug/request documents of follow-up changes is next best thing.

Another consideration is what your sysadmin prefers/knows (if you have one). TRAC (and clones) is excellent combination of bug tracking system, wiki, code repository, and is free/FOSS.

What is great when using integrated system like TRAC (as comparing to stand-alone system like Jira and separate standalone wiki) is that in TRAC, you have consistent markup creating links to other parts of the system. So if you write Bug:1234 in wiki, it will create hyperlink to said bug. Or Changeset:12345 in wiki or in bugzilla comments links to source code viewer with all the changes. Same in comments in source code, when viewed in source code repository viewer. You can break the silos. So all the info (source code, bug/feature, technical documentation of subsystems) lives where it belongs, but is hyperlinked.

Answer (score -1):

- Issue tracking: [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.com/)
- Test cases management: Google Spreadsheets (first step), [Testia Tarantula](http://www.testiatarantula.com/) (next step)
- Web Test automation: Selenium
- Mobile Test automation: Appium